# Magento cart regions restriction

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, restriction, country

my client would like his magento site cart to be restricted to some countries. There is a countries restriction in the System > Config > General panel, but it disablesthe whole website. I would like the site to be usable for everyone, only adding products to cart and checkout would be restricted to some countries.

I didn't find any module doing this yet. Is there one ? Or should I develop my own module ? Any idea how to do that ?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to develop your module and 
just put observer on billing cart save before and check entered country is restricted country or not if yes then enter some message

Comment: Just visit this site  http://snipplr.com/view/56959/   In here $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress(); you can get billing info and country list and just check with restricted country list and display appropriate message hope this help you